# osmdroid: mapController.setZoom(18) more than 18?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

Is there any way to set the Zoom more than 18?

Or is

```
mapController.setZoom(18);
```

maximum?

Comment: The number of supported zoom levels depends entirely on the tile server you are using.

Comment: I have found another tiles-set for me: STAMEN http://maps.stamen.com/watercolor. But how I can set it in my Project?

Comment: I've never used osmdroid myself but this seems to be the official documentation for changing the tile provider: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Map-Sources#using-a-different-tile-source